# How can I call a subroutine declared in another package without prefixing the subroutine name with its package name?

Tags: perl, namespaces, package, subroutine

I'm not entirely sure this is possible, but I would like to simply shorten the name of the subroutine I'm calling declared in another package by just omitting the package name.

For example, I have a module defined:

```
package Package1;

use strict;
use warnings;

BEGIN 
{
  require Exporter;
  our @ISA = qw( Exporter );
  our @EXPORT_OK = qw( subroutine1 );
}

sub subroutine1
{
  print "Hello!$/";
}

return 1;
```

And I have a driver application defined:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Package1;

&Package1::subroutine1;
```

The only way I can seem to shorten the call to `subroutine1` is with making an alias like the following:

```
*s1 = \&Package1::subroutine1;
&s1;
```

Surely I'm being a doofus and missing something here.. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
use Package1;
```

to

```
use Package1 qw( subroutine1 );
```

or change

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( subroutine1 );
```

to

```
our @EXPORT = qw( subroutine1 );
```

I recommend the first change.

Answer (score 1):

You're already using `Exporter`, which is how you achieve this. All you need to do is change your driver application code to

```
use Package1 'subroutine1';
```

in order to tell the `import` method provided by `Exporter` to export your symbol to the calling package.